# MongoDB share-nothing slaves

Tags: mongodb, caching, amazon-ec2, distributed, database

I'd like to use mongodb to distribute a cached database to some distributed worker nodes I'll be firing up in EC2 on demand. When a node goes up, a local copy of mongo should connect to a master copy of the database (say, mongomaster.mycompany.com) and pull down a fresh copy of the database. It should continue to replicate changes from the master until the node is shut down and released from the pool.

The requirements are that the master need not know about each individual slave being fired up, nor should the slave have any knowledge of other nodes outside the master (mongomaster.mycompany.com).

The slave should be read only, the master will be the only node accepting writes (and never from one of these ec2 nodes).

I've looked into replica sets, and this doesn't seem to be possible. I've done something similar to this before with a master/slave setup, but it was unreliable. The master/slave replication was prone to sudden catastrophic failure.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding replicasets: While I don't imagine you could have a set member invisible to the primary (and other nodes), due to the need for replication, you *can* tailor a particular node to come pretty close to what you want:

- Set the newly-launched node to priority 0 (meaning it cannot become primary)
- Set the newly-launched node to 'hidden'

Here are links to more info on [priority 0](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-node-priority-configuration) and [hidden](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-hidden-configuration) nodes.